# Postgres encryption is failing in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, encryption

I am new to postgreSql. I am trying to store some data in my postgres db in encrypted format.
As per the postgres documentation we should use pgcrypto. I have implememted my code in hibernate. if I am trying to store data in plaintext format its storing easily. but when adding @ColumnTransformer then the insertion is failing with the below error message.

i have already executed " CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto; "

Thanks in advance.

```
18:07:46,814 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Hibernate: 
18:07:46,814 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)     insert 
18:07:46,815 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)     into
18:07:46,815 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)         Book
18:07:46,815 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)         (author, name, price, id) 
18:07:46,815 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)     values
18:07:46,815 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)         (?, pgp_sym_decrypt(?, '*************'), ?, ?)

18:07:46,932 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
18:07:46,933 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) ERROR: function pgp_sym_decrypt(character varying, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 56
```

Comment: Pgcrypto returns bytearray. Can you please explain a bit more how you are saving the encrypted/non-encrypted text? I would suggest encrypting it beforehand and then you can save it as character varying. Do you want me to write a sample code you can use to encrypt your data?

Comment: @Akshay I got the issue, now its working as expected thanks for suggestions..

Comment: @sumanta Please share the answer rather than just saying that it is now working.